# Можно ли вшить шрифт в приложение PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, шрифты, qrc

Я использую кастомный шрифт в кнопках. 
Конвертирую **`.py`** в **`.exe`** через `pyinstaller` и кидаю другу, но проблема в том, что у друга шрифт не установлен, а следовательно и на кнопках шрифт поменялся на стандартный.

Можно ли как-нибудь вшить шрифт, чтобы человеку не пришлось его устанавливать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первую очередь надо добавить файл со шрифтами в ресурсы приложения, то есть в файл *.res.

Пусть имя файла шрифта будет somefont.ttf, тогда в коде (лучше в самом начале приложения, сразу после создания переменной приложения):

```
...
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase
...

app = QApplication([])
id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(':<Путь/к/файлу/шрифта/somefont.ttf>')
# Если id равен -1, то шрифт не установлен
if id == -1:
    print('Шрифт somefont не установлен')
```

Теперь в любом месте программы можно обратиться к данному шрифту по имени (без расширения файла):

```
...
font = QFont('somefont')
somelabel.setFont(font)
...
```

p.s. После внесения изменений, файл ресурсов должен быть вновь откомпилирован

p.p.s [Файл ресурсов](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) имеет формат xml и расширение .res. Разместить его можно рядом с файлом main.py вашего приложения.

Если в нем будет только шрифт, то выглядеть он будет так

```xml
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file><path/to/>somefont.ttf</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: @Alexsander не совсем понимаю, где создать .res файл. И как можно внедрить в программу шрифт. Можете попробовать на примере что-ли или объяснить по другому.

Comment: @Сергей дополнил ответ. Если вы работаете из командной строки, то после внесения изменений в файл ресурсов надо его откомпилировать утилиткой pyrcc5 http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pyrcc5.1.html

Comment: спасибо, уже работал с res просто не знал, как это правильно прописать

Comment: Сделал вроде всё, как вы сказали добавил ипмпорт файла, прописал font = ... , но удалив шрифт, и запустив программу через консоль он всё равно не отображает шрифт.

Comment: @Сергей  а вы файл ресурсов откомпилили?

Comment: pyrcc5 -o font.py font.res

Comment: @Сергей если id не равен -1, то шрифт должен быть внедрен в font.py (посмотрите его, есть там какая-нибудь двоичность)? И если на него есть ссылка, то он будет добавлен в конечный экзешник

Comment: А как импортировать QFontDataBase?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108210/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-).

Answer (score 5):

1. Создайте файл ресурсов например

**font_resources.qrc**

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix='/'>
  <file>Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

у меня в папке `Fonts` находится `fontawesome-webfont.ttf`

2. Выполните

   `pyrcc5 font_resources.qrc -o font_resources_rc.py`
3. в своем `main.py`

   - добавьте `import font_resources_rc`
   - пропишите путь к шрифтам  так `":/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"`
4. Проверьте работу `python main.py`
5. `pyinstaller -F -w main.py`

**addApplicationFont_qrc.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QToolButton, QMessageBox 
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QFontDatabase, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt

import font_resources_rc                                                        # +++ !!!

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        fontId = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(":/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf")
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Message", f"fontId -> {fontId}")

        if fontId == 0:
            fontName = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(fontId)[0]
            self.font = QFont(fontName, 30)
        else:
            self.font = QFont()

        btn = QToolButton(self)
        btn.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        btn.setFont(self.font)                                                    # !
        btn.setText(chr(0xf101))
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWnd = MyWindow()
    mainWnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день! @S. Nick я сделал по вашей инструкции, но у меня всё равно слетают шрифты, если в указанной папке нет прописанного шрифта.

Comment: @dutik если у вас что-то не получается - задайте новый вопрос, создайте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему и напишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.