# Подгрузка шрифта в программу. Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qrc

В продолжении темы: [Можно ли вшить шрифт в программу PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1127859/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-pyqt5)

1. я создал (вставил текст в блокнот и сменил расширение файла) файл ресурсов:

```
<qresource prefix='/'>
  <file>Gotham-Light.ttf</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

2. Далее, взял пример(код) из Вашего поста

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QToolButton, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QFontDatabase, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt

import resources                                                        # +++ !!!

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        fontId = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Gotham-Light.ttf")
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Message", f"fontId -> {fontId}")

        if fontId == 0:
            fontName = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(fontId)[0]
            self.font = QFont(fontName, 30)
        else:
            self.font = QFont()

        btn = QToolButton(self)
        btn.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        btn.setFont(self.font)                                                    # !
        btn.setText('sadsdfывуацу')
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWnd = MyWindow()
    mainWnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Т.к. **файл со шрифтом** располагается в той же папке, что и файл **main.py**, я указал путь `"Gotham-Light.ttf"`

3. Запустил в PyCharm'е - всё работает, КРУТО!!!
4. Скомпилировал файл командой: "`pyinstaller -F -w main.py`"
   Но при запуске из директории, где нет шрифта, соответственно шрифт и слетает

Что я сделал не так, не могли бы показать?

Comment: 2. Выполните `pyrcc5 font_resources.qrc -o font_resources_rc.py`

Comment: Да, Ник, это я сделал. Получил Пайтон-файл, его импортировал

Comment: пропишите путь к шрифтам так `":/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"` - обратите внимание на первые два символа `:/`

Comment: Ник, а если файл со шрифтом расположен в той же папке, что и файл main.py?

Comment: попробуйте так `":/Gotham-Light.ttf"`